# Magento 2.4.3-p3 compile error

Tags: magento2, compile

I upgraded a number of module but when I come to compile (bin/magento setup:di:compile) I get the error below.
Anyone know how to fix it?
Thank you
Andy

```
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 104.0 MiBCall to undefined function Composer\Autoload\includeFile()#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(578): include()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload\{closure}()
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1021): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(275): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#16 {main}

You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/mysite`
-bash-4.2$
```

Still struggling with this.

I found some advice to find which class is causing issues by adding echo "Class: ".$path."\n to the /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php file.

Now I'm getting the below when running setup:di:compile

syntax error, unexpected '$realPath' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';' or ','#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload{closure}()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(71): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(36): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getParameterClass()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/OperationFactory.php(109): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(38): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\OperationFactory->create()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(189): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->addOperation()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1021): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(275): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()

Line 432 of the /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432):
Is     (self::$includeFile)($file);

Tu Van I did try removing the vendor folder but this didn't work either.
Hope someone can advise.
Andy

Comment: Hey Andy, try to remove `vendor` directory and run `composer install`.

Comment: disable your custom or third party modules one by one and try compile

Comment: Thanks guys - Tu what is the exact command for composer?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error either correct it by hand or as suggested delete the whole vendor folder and reinstall it. Be careful when editing magento core files.
Here I list some commands that may be useful to you.

If you can manually fix the error after run the command,
composer dump autoload
php bin/magento setup:di:compile .

Otherwise use the command
rm -rf vendor
composer install

Comment: Hi Gennaro 
Before I run the rm -rf vendor composer install
How would I manually fix the syntax error?
The error code suggests the error is at Line 432 of the /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432): 
Which is (self::$includeFile)($file); but this line does contain the ; 
Thank you

Comment: I copied the ClassLoader.php from a working dev site to the effected site and can now run the command bin/magento setup:di:compile
There were differences in the other ClassLoader.php file. I just hope this won't have any negative effect later on.

Comment: Don't worry, I always suggest you copy the files either from the official version of magento on github or I suggest you download a virgin open source version in zip format so you can always go and check the differences.